# Girls und Panzer sensha-do vehicle regulations - mix & match mods?

Tags: girls-und-panzer

Like if you have a Churchill I, but slap the track covers on and that's it, without actually getting a later model that already has it on. Or putting the spaced armor on a different model of a Panzer IV. Everything was made/designed before or during 1945 but just never fitted out that way. Would that be allowed?

Comment: The tanks must be designed or produced before 1945, you can see more rules here, http://gup.wikia.com/wiki/Sensha-dou#Rules